# White frame before video plays in Unity instead of a custom thumbnail

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, video-player

I load a thumbnail before the video starts to play, but later when the video is playing, there is first a white frame and then the video is playing. How can I avoid this white frame??

Here is my code-

```
video.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = thumbnailTex;
//Play the video:
RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(1920, 1080, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
rt.Create();
video.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture =rt;
video.GetComponent<RawImage>().targetTexture=rt;
video.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().url = "www....";
video.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Play();
// white frame, and then the video is playing
```

Comment: What is the line `video.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture =rt;` good for? You are overwriting the texture with a RenderTexture you just created so it will be blanc ..

Comment: without that line, the video never plays... and will always show the static thumbnailTex...  I need to create that special RenderTexture in order to be able to play the video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait first and test if the video is ready to play

It would be better if it's not already to have the above code in a coroutine.  What is happening is you call play before the player has had a chance to download/load the first frame.  Then display your rendertexture.

```
video.GetComponent().url = "...";
    video.GetComponent().Prepare(); 
    while (!video.GetComponent().isPrepared) 
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); 
    video.GetComponent().frame = 0; //just incase it's not at the first frame
    video.GetComponent().Play();
    //now display your render texture
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you very much for this solution to avoid jump frames during the playing of a video!

But there are some changes to do :

- In the "Start" function, I call a coroutine :

  StartCoroutine(PrepareVideoCoroutine());
- In this coroutine, I put :

while (!gameOverGlassVideo.GetComponent().isPrepared) {

```
        gameOverGlassVideo.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Prepare();
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
```

}

> //::: I put the line to prepare the video in the condition and NOT
> outside ::://

- When I want to play the video after, it's was already prepared and there will be not jumping frames!